# Delete dynamically added item by clicking on modal

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to delete dynamically added item by clicking on delete button `.delete` on modal box.
I have one modal and it pops-up when I click on button `<i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis">`.

Code:

```js
function showOptions(object) {
  if (object.target.matches(".fa-ellipsis")) {
    let optionsModal = object.target.querySelector(".optionsModal");

    optionsModal.classList.toggle("hide");
  }
}

function deletePost() {
  // delete specific li-item from the list 
}

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", showOptions(event));
document.querySelector(".delete").addEventListener("click", deletePost);
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="posts-list">
    <li class="posts-list-item">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-option">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="posts-list-item">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-option">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- every li item is added dynamically -->
  </ul>

  <div class="optionsModal hide">
    <p class="delete">Delete</p>
    <p class="cancel">Cancel</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

And I have a problem how to pass to `deletePost` function  specific `<i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis">` when I click on them. I was trying to nest one eventListener in another but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the modal, add a class to the item you clicked on. Then find the item in `deletePost`.

The modal isn't inside `object.target`, so you shouldn't use `object.target.querySelector()` to find it, use `document.querySelector()`.

You shouldn't toggle the `hide` class when clicking on a list items. That will hide the modal if you click on a different item before cancelling the modal (although if you make it truly modal, you shouldn't be able to click on something else). I just remove the class to display the modal.

```js
function showOptions(object) {
  if (object.target.matches(".fa-ellipsis")) {
    let optionsModal = document.querySelector(".optionsModal");
    optionsModal.classList.remove("hide");
    let oldSelected = document.querySelector(".selected");
    if (oldSelected) {
      oldSelected.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    object.target.classList.add("selected");
  }
}

function deletePost() {
  let selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
  if (selected) {
    selected.closest(".posts-list-item").remove();
  }
}

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", showOptions);
document.querySelector(".delete").addEventListener("click", deletePost);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="posts-list">
    <li class="posts-list-item">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-option">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis">Item 1</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="posts-list-item">
      <div class="post">
        <div class="post-option">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-ellipsis">Item 2</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- every li item is added dynamically -->
  </ul>

  <div class="optionsModal hide">
    <p class="delete">Delete</p>
    <p class="cancel">Cancel</p>
  </div>
</body>
```